# How to Upload files and download files to LINODE object storage using Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, linode

I am using SpringBoot for development.

I need to upload and download files from *Linode* Object storage (similar to *Amazon s3 bucket*).

I didn't get any artifact dependency for development. I used Amazon S3 methods for development. But it ended up with an error saying Keys doesn't match s3.

Here is the config code:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig  {
    @Value("${cloud.linode.credentials.access-key}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${cloud.linode.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String accessSecret;

    @Value("${cloud.linode.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 linodeClient() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, accessSecret);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
    }
}
```

How could I solve this? Need *Linode* methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the Linode endpoint with `withEndpointConfiguration`

```java
@Bean
public AmazonS3 linodeClient() {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, accessSecret);
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(
                    "https://" + region + ".linodeobjects.com", region))
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Try without `withRegion`, I've amended my answer.

Comment: I got an error stating that "Only one of Region or EndpointConfiguration may be set. ". What may be the cause. I tried removing "withRegion(region)". Now it runs properly.